# $\sin(75^\circ-r)-\sqrt{2} \sin(r)=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

There is a easy way to solve this equation using the $\arcsin$?

$$\sin(75^\circ-r)-\sqrt{2}\sin(r)=0$$

Sorry I do not remember the trigonometric equations well.
Thank you!

Comment: Make a substitution : $45 - r = \phi$ and use $sin(a+b) = sin(a)cos(b) + sin(b)cos(a)$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sin\alpha\cos r - \cos\alpha\sin r - \sqrt{2}\sin r = 0
$$
$$
\sin\alpha\cos r = \sin r(\cos\alpha +\sqrt{2})
$$
$$
\sin^2\alpha\cos^2r = \sin^2\alpha(1-\sin^2r) = \sin^2r(\cos\alpha +\sqrt{2})^2
$$
$$
\sin^2{r}=\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{(\sin^2\alpha)+(\cos\alpha+\sqrt{2})^2} \rightarrow r = \arcsin\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{(\sin^2\alpha)+(\cos\alpha+\sqrt{2})^2} }
$$

Comment: replace $\alpha = 75°$ or any value you wish.